# Setting minimum length of characters for post

Tags: php, syntax, blogs, strlen

I got code for posting title and body of blog along with few other things. Now I want to set minimum length of characters for title and body using strlen, my code is

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $title=$_POST['title'];
   $body=$_POST['body'];
   $category=$_POST['category'];
   $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
   $body = mysql_real_escape_string($body);
   $posted_by = $user;
   $bio = $bio;
   $id=$_SESSION['id'];
   $date = date ('Y-m-d');
   $body = htmlentities($body);
   if ($title && $body && $category) {
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs (id, title, body, posted_by, bio, category_id, posted) VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$body', '$posted_by','$bio', '$category', '$date')");
      if($query) {
        echo "posted";
      }
      else {
        echo "error";
      }
   }else {
    echo "data missing";
   }
}
```

This code works fine just want to insert minimum characters requirement for title and body. I have tried few if else statements with strlen but I am not programming expert so I get syntax errors.

Comment: What did you try? And what is the minimum chars requirement you want for `$title` and `$body`?

Answer (score 3):

This may help you..

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
           $title=$_POST['title'];
           if(strlen($title)<8)
           {
               //codes to handle error
           }

   $body=$_POST['body'];
   if(strlen($body)<80)
           {
               //codes to handle error
           }
   $category=$_POST['category'];
   $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
   $body = mysql_real_escape_string($body);
   $posted_by = $user;
   $bio = $bio;
   $id=$_SESSION['id'];
   $date = date ('Y-m-d');
   $body = htmlentities($body);
   if ($title && $body && $category) {
      if(strlen($title)>8 && strlen($body>80))
           {

      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs (id, title, body, posted_by, bio, category_id, posted) VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$body', '$posted_by','$bio', '$category', '$date')");
           }
        else {
                  $query = 0;
              }
      if($query) {
        echo "posted";

      }
      else {
        echo "error";
      }
   }else {
    echo "data missing";
   }
```

Comment: nice one, i got message for minimum characters, but then checked my database and their blog has been added to table. could you help on that.

Comment: That is happening because of , if there is no query executed ,the variable $query will not be set.just set a else block under query. $query = 0; see the modified code again. now if there is anything goes wrong it will print "error".

Comment: now it's just error even when all conditions are fulfilled

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the length of your strings you can use "strlen"

```
if(strlen($title)>5 && strlen($body)>5) {
  // $title and $body is more than 5 bytes long
}else{
  // $title or $body is 5 or less than 5 bytes long
}
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: i tried a similar code `if (strlen($title) < 10) {
         echo "title must not be less than 10 characters";
      } 
      else
        if (strlen($body) < 500) {
         echo "body must not be less than 500 characters";
      } 
      else {                                                                                                                           }`   but syntax errors

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Try to paste the syntax error you see

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strlen($title)<=15 && strlen($body)<=500) {
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs (id, title, body, posted_by, bio, category_id, posted) VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$body', '$posted_by','$bio', '$category', '$date')");
      if($query) {
        echo "posted";
      }
}
else
{
echo "Minimum Character Requirments failed.";
}
```